# To remain silent after talking about someone

Tags: behavior, respect

In [this video](https://youtu.be/NrQ0dSusGrQ?t=1184), the interview goes like this (approximate translation from the french) :

"It was the famous story told to abu Bakr... **I will remain silent for a moment, for believers who are watching**, well...

-You can do the...

-No, I don't like this kind of stuff, but I respect **those who would want me to remain silent for a moment**, so I will."

Who is the abu Bakr (I'm not sure about the spelling) he is talking about ?
Does one have to stay silent for a few seconds after mentioning him ?
Or, if I assume correctly that abu Bakr is deceased, does one have to stay silent for a few seconds after mentioning any deceased person ?

I am not a muslim, I am just a curious person who watched a video and wanted to understand.

EDIT: I am probably misspelling the name of Abu Bakr.

EDIT2: Since two people agree on the fact that we are talking about abu Bakr, I change my original, misspelled "Boubakr" to the correct "abu Bakr".

Comment: [Abu Bakr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Bakr), was a companion of the Prophet and the first caliph. I have no idea what he is referring to.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I will edit my post according to the information you just gave me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He is clearly speaking about [abu Bakr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Bakr) listen well (Abou Bakr) or listen repeatedly you will come to this conclusion. So this guy didn't say the typical words of respect after mentioning his name (or that of any companion of the prophet Muhammad or any good and respected person) which are "radia Allah 'anhu رضي الله عنه " (for singular masculine) meaning "May Allah be pleased with him" and remained silence instead.

In case of a typical dead person one would say "rahimahu Allah رحمه الله" (for singular masculine) meaning "May Allah have mercy on him".

There's no rule saying that one should stay silent after mentioning the name of a dead person nor one forcing or recommending Muslims to say the above formulation of respect as is the case for the prophet Muhammad himself:

> Indeed, Allah confers blessing upon the Prophet, and His angels [ask Him to do so]. O you who have believed, ask [ Allah to confer] blessing upon him and ask [ Allah to grant him] peace. ([33:56](https://legacy.quran.com/33/56))

but one could say that it is part of the good manners to do so when mentioning a dead or a person of respect.